# Is "All of my Love" the main influence on this Tame Impala song titled, Led Zeppelin?

Tags: led-zeppelin, influence

I was listening to one of my favorite bands, [Tame Impala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tame_Impala) and a song of theirs on the album *Lonerism* titled, **Led Zeppelin**. Led Zeppelin is already a known influence of Tame Impala's Kevin Parker.

> You wouldn't know it from watching them perform, but Tame Impala
>   exists as the creative arm of one man, 26-year-old Kevin Parker. He's
>   only just released his second album, **Lonerism, a psych-infused pop
>   masterpiece drawing equally from Serge Gainsbourg and harder
>   influences like Led Zeppelin**. But the roots of Tame Impala really go
>   all the way back to when Parker began self-recording in his parents'
>   garage at age 12. https://www.laweekly.com/music/tame-impala-on-the-meaning-of-lonerism-2410711

Listening to the [Led Zeppelin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFQhN0Hwo58) song, I think I can hear a juxtaposing rhythm or melody to Led Zeppelin's [All of my Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwFz3EThGMU) and there's this lyric, "*Is it because I love or is it because I don't? Well, I just don't know."*, but I am not the most musically inclined person when it comes to music composition or music theory and I was wondering if I was on base and/or what other Led Zeppelin  references some of you music aficionados can hear or if any specific influences have been stated elsewhere by Parker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the peppy rhythmic line is very reminiscent of "All of My Love", although the instrumentation is different from that song.  As far as the instruments, it sounds like a very characteristic drum sound and guitar sound for Led Zeppelin as well. Compare this classic Led Zeppelin track [Black Dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBuub4Xe1mw).

The song itself isn't that similar, but the way the drums are miked, and the distortion and effects on the lead guitar are very similar.  As mentioned in the comments on the song, the bass also sounds very much like Zeppelin's bassist, John Paul Jones.  I'd guess that, rather than being inspired by any particular song, this is an affectionate pastiche of Zeppelin's style that brings together characteristic elements from many different source songs.

With that said, here's [an interview with Parker himself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFj0rxyNCtc) on the topic, where he does point to one song in particular:

> Kevin Parker of Tame Impala describes how hearing Led Zeppelin’s [“Good Times Bad Times”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFj0rxyNCtc) made him realize that he could meld his love of rock music with his love of dance music.